# Sub Query in Select query Ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Can I add in sub query in ms access something like :

```
select field1,field2,field3, 
(select field4 from table2 where field5 = field3)  from table1
```

I tried the same and the sub query brings values for every line.I need it to display the value only when `field5 = field3`

Comment: am i correct in understanding question ?

Answer (score 0):

as per discusion you can try this

```
Select field1, field2,field3 + (select
IIF(IsNull(sum(field4)),0,sum(field4)) from table2 where table2field5 = 
table2.fields3) from table1
```

---

Try left join between two table

```
select table1.field1,table1.field2,table1.field3,table2.field4
from table1 left outer join table2 on
 table1.field5= table2.field3
```

---

you can try like this, I think you are trying subquery and you are trying copare table1 column to table2 column

```
select field1,field2,field3, 
 (select field4 from table2 where table2. field5 = field3) from table1
```

or

```
select field1,field2,field3,
  (select field4 from table2 where field5 = table2.field3) from table1
```

Comment: Not compare. I need the query to bring values of field4 only when field5 = field3

Comment: I got you but you want to compare feld5 of table1 to filed3 of table 2 , am i correct ?

Comment: @Nelsons - try join between two table, sorry left join

Comment: @Nelsons - can you tell me error ...I might be wrong in syntax of acess query but logic here is to apply join to get result

Comment: @Nelsons - have you tried join in ms acess as per google this is correct ..as per the SO other answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820564/ms-access-2007-join-on-multiple-fields syntax is correct ....can you please provide error so i can check more on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82634/discussion-between-nelsons-and-pranay-rana).